# Tangent line to a graph and derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My book states:

> Assuming that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $a$, the tangent line to the graph $y = f(x)$ at the point $(a, f(a))$ is given by the equation.
>   $$f(x) - f(a) = f'(a)(x - a)$$

Now let me ask my question.

$f'(a)$ is an **instant change** (when $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$) of the function $f(x)$. If such, I can't get why we multiplying it by the $(x - a)$? I assume you can take **any** $x$ and **any** $a$. Thus the distance between them might be **quite big**. Why the product of non-infinite-small distance and derivative is valid? What am I missing there?

The only way I could agree on that, is when
$$f(x) - f(a) = f'(a)(x - a)$$
$$x \rightarrow a$$
Then the distance $(x - a)$ is infinitely small and thus derivative is applicable.

Comment: Forget the $x-a$ term, what is $f(x)$ doing in there? That makes the equation potentially non-linear. It should be $y - f(a) = f'(a)(x-a)$, I think. This would make the equation into a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$, which means that the equation represents some line. Whether it is indeed the tangent may be discussed afterwards.

Comment: @Arthur $y = f(x)$. So what's the matter which one you pick?

Comment: No, $y = f(x)$ is true for _points on the graph of_ $f$. That's the definition of the graph of a function. However, arbitrary points on a tangent line usually aren't also on the graph of $f$, so that relationship isn't true in general for those points.

Comment: @Arthur, OK, let's take a closer look. 1) We pick up any $a$ where $f(x)$ is indeed differentiable and kind of "fix" it so it never changes later on. 2) So the goal is to get a straight line, 3) which touches original graph at the $f(a)$ point - *at least, but not necessarily only there*. 4) Then $(a, f(a))$ could be treated as constants. 5) As such, if I haven't mistaken nothing so far, then I do not understand the difference between $f(x)$ and $y$ above.

Comment: Let's take the example of $f(x) = x^2$, $a = 1$, and see what happens. Your equation becomes $x^2 - 1^2 = 2\cdot 1(x - 1)$ or $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$. My equation becomes $y - 1^2 = 2\cdot 1(x-1)$ or $y = 2x-1$. Which one looks like the equation for a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more in detail.

1) Straight line:

Let the slope $m$, and a point $(a,b)$ given.

The equation: $y -b = m(x-a).$

a) Line passes through $(a,b)$ ;

b) Has slope $m$ .

Check it.

Being given $f(x)$, $f'(x=a),$ is the 'slope ' $m$ of the tangent line passing through $(a,f(a)).$

If you accept the above statement you are done.

The more interesting question is, how do we get the 'slope ' of the tangent line to a curve $f(x).$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line is a good approximation locally but it need not be a good approximation when $|x-a|$ is huge.

To study the error term, If $f$ is of class $C^{2}$, then for each $x$, there exists a $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that

$$f(x)-p(x)=\frac{f^{(2)}(c)}{2}(x-a)^2$$

here $p(x)$ is the tangent line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very kind of the way your book writes things off.

You have a function $f(x)$ for which a derivative exists in $a$, thus $f'(a)$ is defined.

Then if you want to have the equation of the tangent of the function at point $a$, you have the following:

$y(x)=f(a)+f'(a)\times (x-a)$

Why? Well, the tangent goes by the point $(a,f(a))$. On top of that, this is a line, for which the general equation is $y(x)=cx+d$.

Let's do $y(a)=c\times a +d=f(a)$. And the rate of the line is equal to the derivative in point $a$, thus $c=f'(a)$. You have then $d=f(a)-f'(a)\times a$.

Thus the original equation! $y(x)=f'(a)\times x+f(a)-f'(a)\times a$...

Comment: You helped me out. My books seems be mistrustful ;)

Comment: But still. Does it mean that $a$ and $x$ could be literally any points, where $y(x)$ is defined and could be differentiated? Obviously, the bigger $|x - a|$ distance, the worse approximation?

Comment: $x$ is a variable, while $a$ is a fixed point (the one on which you take the tangent). On the topic of approximation, clearly the tangent is only a good approximation when you are very close to the point of tangence. When you increase the distance from the tangence point, you are losing your precision and the tangent is not an approximation of the function anymore. The answer from Siong Thye Goh even gives a measure of the precision of the approximation when the function is twice differentiable.